# How to call controller->method with alto router

Tags: php, altorouter

I'm trying to learn how to use alto router and what I want i'ts "pretty simple".

exemple:

- "/" should call "AppController->index()"
- "/profil" should call "ProfilController->profil()"
- /profil/1" should call "ProfilController->profilById()

etc...

This is what I've tried so far:

```php
<?php
use App\Controller\AppController;
require './vendor/autoload.php';
putenv("BASE_URL=/formulaire-php");
 
// Router
$router = new AltoRouter();
$router->setBasePath('/formulaire-php');
$router->map('GET', '/', 'AppController#index');
$match = $router->match();

if ($match === false) {
    echo "404";
} else {
    list($controller, $action) = explode('#', $match['target']);
    if (is_callable(array($controller, $action))) {
        call_user_func_array(array($controller,$action), array($match['params']));
    } else {
        // here your routes are wrong.
        // Throw an exception in debug, send a  500 error in production
    }
}
```

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

composer.json

```json
{
  "require": {
    "altorouter/altorouter": "^2.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/controller/"
    }
  }
}
```

AppController:

```php
namespace App\Controller;

class AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo "I index code + return index view here";
    }
```

for now I have no error at all so it's difficult to know what's going on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

Solution 1 : Put all routes in index.php

index.php

```php
$router = new AltoRouter();
$router->setBasePath('/formulaire-php');
$router->map('GET', '/', 'AppController#create') //controller#method
$match = $router->match();
 

if (!$match) {
    echo "404";
    die;
}

if ($match) {
    require_once './src/view/template/header.php';
    list($controller, $action) = explode('#', $match['target']);
    $controller = 'App\\Controller\\' . $controller;
    $controller = new $controller;
    if (is_callable(array($controller, $action))) {
        call_user_func_array(array($controller,$action), array($match['params']));
    }
    require_once './src/view/template/footer.php';
}
```

composer.json

```json
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/"
    }
  }
```

AppController

```php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;

class AppController extends AbstractController
{
    public function create()
    {
        echo "hello"
    }
```

solution2 : put the routes in a config/routes.php and call it in index.php

src/Config/Routes.php

```php
namespace App\Config;

class Routes
{
//The method getRoutes() will return a array with all routes
    public static function getRoutes(): array
    {
        return [
          ['GET', '/', 'AppController#create'],
          ['POST', '/save', 'AppController#save'],
          ['GET', '/save', 'AppController#save'],
          ['GET', '/user/[i:id]', 'AppController#test'],
        ];
    }
}
```

index.php
The foreach loop will loop over all routes.

```php
<?php

require './vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Config\Routes;

// Router
$router = new AltoRouter();
$router->setBasePath('/formulaire-php');

foreach (Routes::getRoutes() as $route) {
    $router->map(...$route);
}

$match = $router->match();
 

if (!$match) {
    echo "404";
    die;
}

if ($match) {
    require_once './src/view/template/header.php';
    list($controller, $action) = explode('#', $match['target']);
    var_dump($controller);
    $controller = 'App\\Controller\\' . $controller;
    $controller = new $controller;
    if (is_callable(array($controller, $action))) {
        call_user_func_array(array($controller,$action), array($match['params']));
    }
    require_once './src/view/template/footer.php';
}
```